# Get root elements for list of children in hierarchical table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, h2, common-table-expression

I have the following 2 tables, with hierarchical data in the first one:

COMPANIES:

```
COMPANY_ID    PARENT_COMPANY_ID
----------    -----------------
1             NULL
2             1
3             2
4             3
5             NULL
6             5
```

USERS:

```
USER_ID       COMPANY_ID
-------       ----------
1             1
2             4
3             5
4             6
```

I would like to make a query which outputs user ids next to their root company ids. I have tried with the following Common Table Expression (CTE) query, but it fails to output users that are directly under a root company:

Query:

```
WITH ROOT (COMPANY_ID, ROOT_ID) AS (
  SELECT
    CHILD.COMPANY_ID,
    PARENT.COMPANY_ID
  FROM COMPANIES CHILD
  INNER JOIN COMPANIES PARENT
  ON CHILD.PARENT_COMPANY_ID = PARENT.COMPANY_ID
  WHERE
    PARENT.PARENT_COMPANY_ID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    C.COMPANY_ID,
    ROOT.ROOT_ID
  FROM ROOT
  INNER JOIN COMPANIES C
  ON ROOT.COMPANY_ID = C.PARENT_COMPANY_ID
  )
SELECT
  U.USER_ID,
  R.ROOT_ID
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN ROOT R
ON U.COMPANY_ID = R.COMPANY_ID;
```

Actual output:

```
USER_ID    ROOT_COMPANY_ID
-------    ---------------
4             5
2             1
```

Expected output:

```
USER_ID    ROOT_COMPANY_ID
-------    ---------------
1             1
2             1
3             5
4             5
```

So my query is missing the users with user id 1 and 2 with their respective root companies  1 and 5.

I have created this sqlfiddle with my example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36d33a/1

What am I missing here?

I am using Oracle 11 but using H2 for unit tests. So my query needs to be a CTE query and not an Oracle connect by query since H2 only understands the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `COMPANY_ID` as both `COMPANY_ID` and `ROOT_ID` for root companies:

```sql
WITH ROOT(COMPANY_ID, ROOT_ID) AS (
   SELECT COMPANY_ID, COMPANY_ID FROM COMPANIES WHERE PARENT_COMPANY_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
   SELECT C.COMPANY_ID, ROOT.ROOT_ID FROM COMPANIES C JOIN ROOT
       ON C.PARENT_COMPANY_ID = ROOT.COMPANY_ID
) SELECT USER_ID, ROOT_ID FROM USERS JOIN ROOT
    ON USERS.COMPANY_ID = ROOT.COMPANY_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's classical Hierarchical Query including `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` together with `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic Function to filter out the root company in the first query(subquery) for `companies` table, and then join with the `users` table :

```
WITH company AS
(
 SELECT c.company_id, 
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT NVL(c.parent_company_id,c.company_id) AS root_company_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.company_id ORDER BY level DESC) AS rn
   FROM companies c
CONNECT BY PRIOR c.company_id = c.parent_company_id
)
SELECT u.user_id, c.root_company_id
  FROM company c
  JOIN users u
    ON u.company_id = c.company_id
 WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61d95dc669b1bd1601fe86f05f34ff5a)</kbd>